# Is the servlet specification in webapp's web.xml required in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, web-applications

I have a webapp that runs in a tomcat engine.
In the web.xml file, the <[DOCTYPE]> element contains a reference to the servlet specification.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd" [
]>
```

I noticed that if I do not have internet access, then my webapp doesn't start up properly. But if I simply remove the reference to the servlet specification, then my webapp seems to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app [
]>
```

I sometimes need to run demos off my laptop using this tomcat webapp and a local browser. I may not always have internet access which is why I need to remove this restriction.

My question is, is there any sort of side-effects (which I have yet to notice) from not including the servlet specification?

I also noticed that my web.xml has a servlet 2.4 specification in schema-style:

```
<web-app version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

According to this (http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/java_app/tomcat6/tomcat6_web_config.htm), different servlet versions includes the specification in different places. But it's weird that it has always included both.

Thanks in advance,
Kane